# how to round up string if necessary if not just leave it like that

Tags: java

My requirement goes like this

- if it is 1.0 output is 1
- if it is 1.00 output is 1
- if it is 1.5 output is 1.5
- if it is 1.25 output is 1.25
- sometimes it may be empty

I tried like this:

```
public class roundup 
{
    public static String Convert_Roundup(Float Amount, String element)  
    {
        if (Amount > 0)
        {
            LEFT(Amount,INDEX(Amount,element)    
        }
        else 
            return Amount;
        }       
    }
}
```

As i am beginner user of Java and Talend I got to write a routine so that i can reuse it anytime.

My old routine which rounds any float value to two decimals:

```
public class decimal 
{
    public static String ConvertTo_TwoDecimals(Float Amount) 
    {
        String Amount1 = "";
        if (Amount != null) 
        {
            DecimalFormat myFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
            Amount1 = myFormat.format(Amount);
        }
        return Amount1;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do we differentiate between 1.0 and 1.00?

Comment: 1.0 -> 1, 1.00 -> 1.00? That's not a requirement, that's a set of contradictory examples.

Comment: @all i have changed that 1.00-> 1

Comment: I've tried this but its not working!!

public class roundup {
    
    public static Float Convert_Roundup(Float Amount, String element){
         Float result = (Amount - int(Amount));
     if (result == 0)
    {
     return int(Amount);
    }
     else return Amount; 
    }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not changing your data type from float to double and then use a printf function? Is that where you are putting your output to? For example 
System.out.println("The number is: %1.2f", example);   Do you have to use a float?